# defの使い方について

Tags: python

python初心者です。
defの使い方について質問させてください。

```py
def test():
    test = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(test)
```

上のように書いて実行したところ、下のような結果になりました。

```py
<function test at 0x0000025BA905C1E0>
```

以下のような結果を期待していたのですが、なぜこうならなかったのでしょうか。

```py
 ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

改善点を教えてください。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/230798

Comment: @nijihan さん、回答が投稿されると、質問者は回答を承認することができます。過去のご質問もあわせてご確認いただけると幸いです。参考：[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: その機能は知りませんでした。教えてくださりありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ふたつの勘違いがありそうです。期待する出力を返すコードはおそらくこれです。

```
def test():
    return ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(test())
```

勘違いしてらっしゃいそうなのは次のふたつです。

- 「関数そのもの」と「関数呼び出しの結果返ってきた値」を区別する。`test` は関数そのもの、`test()` は関数呼び出しの結果返ってきた値です。`<function test at 0x0000025BA905C1E0>` というのは関数そのものを `print` したときに出てくるものです。
- 関数から値を返すには `return` を使う。また、Python では関数の中で何もせずそのまま変数に代入すると、その関数の中でだけ有効な変数（ローカル変数）に代入される。

最後に、元々のソースコードが何をしていたのか説明します。

```
# 関数 test を定義
def test():
    # ローカル変数 test にリストを代入
    test = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    # そのまま何も返さず関数終了

# 関数自体を出力
print(test)
```

Answer (score 2):

以下2点が原因です。

- `print()`の`test`に`()`が付いていないので関数呼び出しになっていない。`test`関数の情報を`print`することになっている
- `test`関数が戻り値を返していない。

このように修正すると良いでしょう。

```
def test():
    test = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return test

print(test())
```

---

ちなみに、`test = ['a', 'b', 'c']`(関数名 = 値)で戻り値を設定できる言語があって、それはVisualBasicやVBAです。それらの記憶があって、このような記述になったのかもしれませんね。
[Function プロシージャ Visual Basic | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/function-procedures)
[Functionプロシージャ - プロシージャ - Excel VBA入門](https://www.officepro.jp/excelvba/sub/index6.html)